# Javascript popup triggers browser quirks mode

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, popup, quirks-mode

I have a simple javascript snippet to show a popup with a textArea and a button inside:

```
var popup = open("", "Popup", "width=400,height=400,top=250,left=550");
var area = popup.document.createElement("textarea"); 
var but = popup.document.createElement("button"); 
popup.document.body.appendChild(area); 
popup.document.body.appendChild(but);
```

if I use it in browser console it works fine, as expected.
I'm trying to make a clickable bookmark on my bookmarks bar (Firefox) but if i put these few lines in a bookmark (setting as bookmark url `Javascript: var popup = open....` ) then I'm facing some problems, while the popup still appears as expected, the main browser page turns blank with only `[object HTMLButtonElement]` written in the upper left corner, then looking at the browser console there is a warning about quirks mode enabled. Why is it so?

Comment: what does your bookmarklet line look like exactly?

Comment: @epascarello javascript: followed by the exact 5 lines described above